# WPF tooltip for file operations

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I am implementing a texteditor in WPF. I am pretty new to WPF and C#. I am able to get tooltip for "Cut","Copy","Paste" options. But how do I get tooltip for File operations like "New","Open","Save","Save_As" and "Close"? Also I do see that when I edit a file in my Richtextbox, the editor does not indicate that file is changed. How do I implement this feature? Any help is appreciated.

```
<MenuItem Header="_File">
                    <MenuItem Header="_New" Click="New_Click"/>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Open" Click="Open_Click"/>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Save" Click="Save_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\FileSave.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Save As" Click="Save_As_Click">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\FileSaveAs.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Close" Click="Close_Click"/>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Click="Exit_Click"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Cut" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" ToolTip="Cut">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\EditCut.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" ToolTip="Copy">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\EditCopy.png" Height="21"></Image>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Paste" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" ToolTip="Paste">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\EditPaste.png" Height="21"></Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Undo" Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" ToolTip="Undo">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\EditUndo.png" Height="21"></Image>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Redo" Command="ApplicationCommands.Redo" ToolTip="Redo">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="C:\Users\stambi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PatternEditor\PatternEditor\Images\EditRedo.png" Height="21"></Image>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do the same thing with `New, Open, Save` you have to define the `ToolTip` property.

Regarding how to determine if the file has changed depends on how you want to build it. Assuming you have `Dock Windows` as the parent of the `RichTextBox` Do you want an indicator that gives a `*` in the `Header` of the `DockWindow` or do you just want to know if the file has changed then you can use an event called `TextChanged`.